# How to import a module that is already available by using only typings in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a widget for a website that already has jQuery available using TypeScript. So my output will be embedded into the host website and I want to make use of jQuery that is already loaded by the host website.

To simulate the production environment, I added the host website references by putting some `link` and `script` tags in the header of my HTML wrapper development code.

To use jQuery in TypeScript my initial idea is to simply install `@types/jquery` and import it using `import $ from 'jquery';`. This compiles, but it fails, because the module does not exist, obviously:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' [...]

How to let TypeScript know that jQuery is already available in my application, so it uses `window.jQuery`, but with typings?

Comment: If you are using webpack, set the `externals` in your config: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: @LindaPaiste Post it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has a property `externals` in the configuration that is used for exactly this purpose.  It tells the bundler that this package does not need to be included in the bundle because it will already be loaded in the environment.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
  },
};
```

More info can be found in the [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

Answer (score 1):

I can use this code, instead of the import, to bypass the error and make it work:

```
const jQuery: JQueryStatic = window['jQuery'] as JQueryStatic;
```

Although it's better to configure jQuery as external within the webpack configuration as Linda states, although not every environment allows editing the webpack configuration without opting out.